# Split long and slow jupyter-notebook in separate blocks

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

**Background:**

I have a very long jupyther-notebook storing a lot of large numpy arrays.
As I use it for documenting a project, the jupyther notebook consists of several independent blocks and one import block (necessary for all other blocks). The notebook gets very slow, after many cells have been calculated, so I want to find a way to speed things up. The question below, seems the most solid and convenient solution to me at the moment, but I am open to other ideas.

**My Question:**

Is there a convenient way, to define independent blocks of a jupyther-notebook and execute them separately from each other with just a view clicks?

**Ideas I had so far:**

Always put the latest block on the top of my notebook (after the include statements). At the end of this block write a `raise` command to prevent the execution of further blocks: This is somehow messy and I can not execute blocks further down in the document by just a view clicks.

Split the notebook in separate notebook documents: This helps, but I want to keep better overview over my work.

`delete` all variables, which were used in the current block after it's execution: For whatever reason, this did not bring a considerable speedup. Is it possible, that I did something wrong here?

Start the browser I use for the jupyther-notebook with some nice value (I am using linux): This does not improve the performance in the notebook, but at least the computer keeps running fast and I can do something else on it, while waiting for the notebook.

The workaround I will end up, if I don't find a better solution here, is to define variables

```
actBlock1=False
actBlock2=True
actBlock3=False
```

and put if statements in all cells of a block. But I would prefer something which produces less unnecessary ifs and indents, to keep my work clean.

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Jupyter Notebook Extensions package](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/), and, in particular, at the [Freeze](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/freeze/readme.html) extension. It will allow you to mark cells as "frozen" which means they cannot be executed (until you "unfreeze" them, that is).

For example, in this image:

[image: Frozen cells]

The blue-shaded cells are "frozen" (you can select that with the asterisk button in the toolbar). After clicking "Run all" only the non-frozen cells have been executed.

Comment: thank you very much! It will be a bit of work to activate/deactivate full blocks, but this will help in any case

Comment: I tried it out and it exactly solves my problem. I will do some more testing on it and mark the question as solved then